# Qt not recognizing designer

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface

I've got Qt environment to program.

However, even if i do have qt designer, the icon on qt creator (i presume is the compilation of them all) is grayed out and it doesn't allow me to connect directly from there to the creator IDE. I'm new to this, so I hope some help even if I'm asking something very basic.

I have Qt designer from outside the environment, I just don't know why are this not recognizing it.

Answer (score 0):

The designer icon is grayed out until you open a .ui file.